# How can I animate Android Spinners?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-spinner

My App is a temperature conversion  app , In that I've two spinners, one will contain list of source metric the other will contain list of target metrics (Apparently loaded from the same Array adapter) in the app I've a interchange button. The functionality of the interchange button is it will change the source side spinner metric to target side spinner metric and vice versa. 
i.e If I've Celsius selected in the source spinner and Kelvin in the target spinner and if I press the interchange button the metric name in the spinners will be swapped(values in the corresponding text box will be calculated based on the new source and target metric).

sample code:

```
            int srcposn = sourceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int tgtposn = targetSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            sourceSpinner.setSelection(tgtposn);
            targetSpinner.setSelection(srcposn);
```

My question is when I press the interchange button the swap is happening but there is no proper animation which denotes the swap has happened.
when I gave the app to my friends they couldn't identify the swap has really happened. Even I couldn't notice it :) .

Can you please give some suggestions on how to make the swap look more obvious to the users.
Sorry, I couldn't post the image as I'm new to this forum.
[Image grab of the App](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1svQHR2dZPnTHoYE37E88_ltd96k6eLbJbznnrfOaI2w/edit)

Thanks in advance for the help.!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Android Animations are not used in this cases. To tell the user that some values changed when he pressed a button I usually popup a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html), it is simple and effective. And if you dont like the design of it you can customize it with what you desire. It is all explained on the link I sent ([Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)).

Just use this in your button `OnClickListener()`:

```
int srcposn = sourceSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
int tgtposn = targetSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
sourceSpinner.setSelection(tgtposn);
targetSpinner.setSelection(srcposn);

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(
                    HomeActivity.this, 
                    "Units Successfully Changed", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

EDIT:

However if you prefer to do an effect like highlighting the spinners for a few seconds...
I couldn't find any good help on the web for this problem, so I followed the basics of what it is done with the `ImageViews`. To animate `ImageViews` it is used an `ImageSwitcher` and created 2 `ImageViews` equals, so basically this is the same thing. The idea is to create two new `Spinners`, aligning them to the Top and Left of the others, with a function like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@link Spinner} which overlays another
 * @param spinner {@link Spinner} to overlay
 * @return The new {@link Spinner}
 */
private Spinner createNewSpinner(Spinner spinner){
    LayoutParams spinnerParams = new LayoutParams(spinner.getWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    spinnerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, spinner.getId());
    spinnerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, spinner.getId());

    Spinner overlaySpinner = new Spinner(HomeActivity.this);
    overlaySpinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerParams);

    return overlaySpinner;
}
```

For the effect I think you can create something like this, but i'm not sure if it works 100% so for having more support read [Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:background="@drawable/bg_orange"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="400"
/>
```

To load the animation you can use this code, but because you want to trigger the effect in 2 `Spinners` simultaneously I'm not sure if you can do everything following this idea. That's why I didn't tell you this before.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.disapear);
sourceSpinner.startAnimation(animation);
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Though Toast is good idea, but I would prefer some other interesting ideas so that even the interchange of the values happen with some kinda animation or at least in way that user knows.. Or using a customized Spinner will help in some ways?

Comment: When I said "Customize it" I'm talking about the Toast.
However if you don't want to use it and really want an animation...
Do you have any idea of what sort of animation you want?

Comment: I'm not sure really because I couldn't find any example which does that. How about the default spinner selection color displayed when the items are interchanged. My application uses orange as the main theme so when I press the interchange the text should hide from spinner , Orange color with the changed value comes in the spinner and the color goes away after a second.. Hope I conveyed what I intended..

Comment: Guys please give me some rope here.. I don't need the code or anything, just some guide..

Comment: Ok then, so I will give you my idea. See the edit of my answer